# Merge rows based on a condition

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to merge a collection of rows based on a condition in Spark SQL using a sql query ?

If the difference between `purch_dt` of two consecutive rows placed in order (`line_num`) is less than `5`  days, then combine them into `1` row and output that merged row and the merged row should have the max value of `purch_dt` for that group. I tried using the `LEAD` function but I can't get it to reset after each false condition is encountered and consider the following rows as a new group. I am not being able to get the max of `purch_dt` for each such group.

Input:

```
orderid | line_num | purch_dt
1 | 1 | 10-02-2020
1 | 2 | 12-02-2020
1 | 3 | 14-02-2020
1 | 4 | 21-03-2020
1 | 5 | 23-03-2020
```

Output:

```
orderid | purch_dt
1 | 14-02-2020 -- 1 - 3 combined into 1 row because difference is <5 between each
1 | 23-02-2020 -- 4 - 5 combined into 1 row because difference is <5 between each
```

`Total Output rows = 2` because we have `2` groups.

Please note that line_num 4 is used as a set break since its difference between line_num = 3 is greater than 5. Hence it should have its own merged record set.

I have the sql below so far, but I can't get to break out and create the groups.

```
create temporary view next_dt as
select
order,
LEAD(purch_dt) over (partition by orderid order by line_num asc) AS next_purch_dt,
purch_dt
from orders;

select * 
from (
select 
order,
CASE WHEN datediff(next_purch_dt, purch_dt) < 5 OR next_purch IS NULL THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END AS flg
from 
next_dt)
WHERE flg = 'Y';
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

Slight change in the requirements:-

The comparison has now to be made between two different fields in consecutive records - `purch_dt` of the current record and the `return_dt` of the next record.
Also, when a **merged** record group is being output, it should have the `purch_dt` populated with the value of the record with the least `line_num` in that **group**. And the `return_dt` column populated with the value of the max `line_num` record of that same group.

Input:

```
orderid | line_num | purch_dt   | return_dt
1       |    1     | 10-02-2020 | 10-02-2020 
1       |    2     | 12-02-2020 | 13-02-2020
1       |    3     | 14-02-2020 | 14-02-2020
1       |    4     | 21-03-2020 | 23-02-2020
1       |    5     | 23-03-2020 | 24-02-2020
```

Output:

```
orderid | purch_dt   | return_dt
1       | 10-02-2020 | 14-02-2020
1       | 21-03-2020 | 24-02-2020
```

`Total Output rows = 2` because we have `2` groups.

Note that each output record contains the `purch_dt` of the record with min `line_num` in that group. And contains `return_dt` populated as per the record with max `line_num` in that group.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got this, below query has worked for me,

```
sql("""create temporary view next_dt_orders as
       select * 
            from (
                   select 
                      orderid,line_num,purch_dt,
                      case when datediff( 
                                  (lead(purch_dt) over (partition by orderid order by line_num asc)), 
                                  purch_dt) < 5 
                                 then "N" 
                                 else "Y" 
                           end as flag
                   from 
                      orders) tab
       where
          flag='Y'""")
     
sql("select * from next_dt_orders").show()  

+-------+--------+----------+----+
|orderid|line_num|  purch_dt|flag|
+-------+--------+----------+----+
|      1|       3|2020-02-14|   Y|
|      1|       5|2020-03-23|   Y|
+-------+--------+----------+----+
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have updated the question with a slight modification to the requirements. How can I populate the `purch_dt` of the min `line_num` record in the **group** and populate the `return_dt` as the max `line_num` in that **group**. Please let me know if additional information is required.